# What do you call grinds in Chinese?

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure if this word exists in the states or even in the UK but in Ireland we call extra tuition outside of school grinds. I give maths and physics grinds to a number of students.

I am aware of the term 家教 but it just doesn't feel right in the context that I want to use it.

How would I say for example :

1. I give maths grinds to 3 students.
2. I offered free grinds to my students.
3. Giving grinds is good money.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If grinds mean tutoring/ tuition in this context, we can just simply translate grinds as 补习.

If you need to specific, you can say 校外补习  (outside school tutoring) or 私人补习  (private tutoring)

> I give maths grinds to 3 students. - 我给3名学生做数学补习。

> I offered free grinds to my students. - 我向学生提供免费补习。

> Giving grinds is good money. - 给人补习的收入不错

Usually, 给人补习 (give tuition) is a job for 家庭教师 (private teacher), but anyone qualified can offer tuition to anyone who needs it.

Comment: I never understand why people would write sentences like 我给3名学生做数学补习.  Why can't they just write "我给3名学生补习数学"? Once my wife said: " I'm going to 做運動." I asked her: "運動 is already a verb. Why do you put another verb in front of it? Why can't you just said "I am going to 運動?" She became furious.

Comment: @ joehua I just translate "I give maths grinds to 3 students." word by word literally to avoid confusing the asker. If the original sentence was "I tutor three students maths' I would translate it as '我给3名学生补习数学' as you suggested. The asker may wonder why I changed 补习 from noun to verb

Comment: @ joehua In "I'm going to 做運動" It is perfectly fine with 做(v) followed by a noun 運動(n) .  She might want to emphasize 運動 as a noun. She would not say "I am going to  做打老公" because "打老公" cannot be treated as a noun like 運動 does. So, relax, Not every words can be either noun or verb, and not all nouns work with the verb  做

Comment: Yes. It's perfectly fine except there is a 贅字。This is a minor case. There are much more offensive cases in newspapers. Sooner or later, they'll show up here.

Comment: Example: 做 in '去美容院做按摩'  is not a 贅字 because '去美容院按摩' could mean you are the one giving instead of getting a  按摩